# C# DateTimePicker change MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, winforms, components, custom-controls, datetimepicker

I created my own MonthCalendar (selecting multiple things and more changes) and I want to use it with DateTimePicker. Take DateTimePicker and when click on right button then it shows my custom calendar. Is there easy way? Or I should creat it all by myself as in this tutorial: http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=70925
Thanks

Comment: What UI language are you using? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.net? ASP.net MVC? WinForms?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it. It´s Winforms

Comment: My guess is you'll want to start from scratch with Winforms, although you might be able to get a slight head-start by using visual inheritance if DateTimePicker is not sealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a little hack, but it should work just fine.

First we check at OnSizeChanged what button we have, the big(with icon) or the small (without icon). If its the big button the button has a with of 35pixel the small has 18pixel.

Then we listen to to the window messages. if mousedown occurs we check at which location the user clicked. Therefore we translate the lParam to the X/Y Location. If the X Position is at the button-area we go to our custom methode and show our calendar. After the method we return from the method or the DateTimePicker will show its own calendar too.

Additionaly we override the ShowUpDown Property an set it Browseable(false). But we could also check if ShowUpDown is true and let the DateTimePcker handle the click in this case.

Here is the code:

```
class DateTimePickerEX : DateTimePicker {

    const int WM_MOUSEDOWN = 0x201;

    int paddingright = 0;

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);

        int textwidth = 0;

        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics()) {
            textwidth = (int)g.MeasureString(this.Text, this.Font).Width;
        }

        if (textwidth > this.Width - 35 - 22) {
            paddingright = 18;
        } else {
            paddingright = 35;
        }

    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEDOWN) {
            DWORD dw = new DWORD(m.LParam);
            int x = dw.HI;
            int y = dw.LO;

            if (x > this.Width - paddingright) {
                OnButtonClick();
                return;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    [EditorBrowsable( EditorBrowsableState.Never ), Browsable(false)]
    public new bool ShowUpDown {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void OnButtonClick() {
        //-----------------------------------
        //####  Show your MonthCalendar  ####
        //-----------------------------------
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct DWORD {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int Word;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public short HI;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public short LO;

        public DWORD(IntPtr word) {
            this.HI = 0;
            this.LO = 0;
            this.Word = (int)word;
        }

        public static DWORD Empty {
            get {
                return new DWORD() {
                    Word = 0
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is what I want a can you help me with showing monthcalendar? I am doing it by this.Controls.Add(calendar); but it is that small textbox in datepicker. I know It is because it is not form but I really add control to that small window but how can I just show it rigth, thanks

Comment: You shouldn't add it to a control if you want the same behavior as the original monthcalendar (showing the monthcalendar even outside the form if neseccary/required, and hide if the user clicked somewhere else). You could use a ToolStripDropDown and add your MonthCalendar with ToolStripControlHost. An other way would be creating an own form with global hook and without stealing focus.